# c++ circular buffer using large disk file

Tags: c++

I need to write an efficient circular buffer which uses a disk file.  Reason for that is that the buffer is typically large (>4GB) since this buffer is used as a PVR timeshift buffer.

More technically:

- this buffer is storing a transport stream (TS) file which consists of packets of 188 bytes (TS packets)
- There is one writer and one or two readers.  The reader has to be able to seek into the file (this occurs if we want to fast forward or go back in time)
- The process hosting this implementation is 32 bit only.

I tried many implementations but could not find something that performs properly.  I always run into issues where disk i/o would make my video reader stutter when it occurs.

I am now to the point to try having a hybrid solution where I would combine the usage of a memory buffer and a disk file.  A thread would be triggered to write/fill the buffer whenever it would be full (writer) or depleted (reader) of packets.

Does anyone have an idea on what to use?  I have seen someone mentioning that I could use Boost, but I am unable to figure out how to have a simple architecture to support circular buffer+memory mapped file+large disk file.

Edit:
- It seems that my question was not following the rules.  Sorry about that, I am new to this and might have missed the way to properly formulate it so that an answer could be properly formulated.
- It seems it was not that bad because Michael managed to confirm that I need an Hybrid solution.
- Thanks to Toby for providing a hint to look at MythTV

Comment: HDD or SSD? What rate are you writing data?

Comment: On 32 bit OS I'd split the buffer in two parts.

Comment: Can you just read the relevant implementation in MythTV or similar, and learn from that?

Comment: On SSD, I have no issue so far, the disk probably seeks fast enough to fulfill the job in the reiquried amount of time.  I have problems mainly on high capacity, low RPM HDD.

Comment: I will look at the MythTV implementation and see if I can reuse the relevant part, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have in fact 3 separate circular buffers, each with its own characteristics.  That's great, since the complexity can be divided in three tasks

- 1 **input** buffer, for incoming video

  - unit of storage: 188 byte TS packet.
  - Input from video stream.
  - output to main on-disk circular buffer.
  - optionally, this buffer could grow within limits, to accommodate machine load.
- 1 main **on-disk** buffer.

  - unit of storage: 4096 bytes, or 21 x 188 byte TS packet (148 bytes header  + 3948 bytes payload), you could also use another multiple of 4096 for item size. Using a multiple of 4096 can greatly improve disk i/o response.
  - This is a fixed sized file.
  - input from input buffer
  - outputs to output buffer.
  - pointers into this buffer (head, tail) can be kept in memory.
- 1 **output** buffer

  - unit of storage: 188 byte TS packet.
  - mainly for stutter-free viewing.
  - fixed-size

Input and output buffer, you can create with boost::circular_buffer.  Growing the input buffer is optional, but recommended, so this complexity should be added last, once the system is running.

The on-disk circular buffer can be implemented using either buffered or memory mapped i/o.  AFAIK, this has to be a custom class, but implementation is rather straightforward.

You will also need to write another custom class so this system looks like a single circular buffer from the outside.  This class could have 2 independent worker threads, with high priority, or two tasks using boost.asio running on a single thread for disk access (this would simplify locking quite a bit and avoid race conditions):

- first task is charged with offloading excess from input buffer to the on-disk buffer.
- second task is charged to keep the output buffer filled to capacity.

[EDIT] Since most access to the on-disk buffer is done sequentially, I'd favor regular buffered I/O, the OS disk cache has look-ahead, and it is portable.  The block sizes presented here should be tested and played with to obtain the best performance.  Smaller block will introduce more calls to the OS, while a larger block size will introduce more latency.  You'll need to find the right balance for your app and the target host.

Comment: The on-disk buffer can be multiples of 192512 bytes, which is the smallest number that divides evenly by both 4096 and 188.

Comment: Memory mapping won't work on a 32-bit system for multi-GB files.

Comment: That depends on the target operating system.  In 32-bit Windows, there is no  4GB limit. But buffered I/O will work regardless of the OS, if it is less than 15 years old.

Comment: @Mark That is a bit large to wait on, since fragmentation can add quite a bit of latency.   4096 is a common cluster size, and yes, it is a bit small.  Look ahead disk caching can help quite a bit here.

Comment: Thanks Michael, This is something that I was thinking of if you look at my question regarding the option of a Hybrid solution.  I will go that way and see if I can manage to make this work.  I thought that maybe I missed some solution that were already done (why reinvent the wheel ;)) but I guess I will have to design it.  I will look at MythTV implementation to see if I could reuse part of that stuff!  Thanks!

Comment: I had to diverge a bit from this design as there is too much latency introduced due to the fact that I must write using blocks of 192512 bytes.  Mainly this is because for low bandwidth channels, this is just too much buffering.  What I had to do is to complexify things so that the input buffer can provide data directly to the output buffer even though the data has not been written to disk yet.  The design is getting a bit more complicated.

Comment: I would have gone for much smaller packets, Even if that meant wasting some space in padding.  10% space padding waste is not much for improved bandwidth.  A 190K packet size is fine for fnal storage, but obviously not ideal for fast r/w access.

Answer (score -1):

Even though your program is only 32-bit (I feel for you there!!!) all is not lost. You can use a RAM-DISK, then you can seek to your hearts content.

An example  [Gavotte Ramdisk Utility](https://www.megaleecher.net/RAMDisk).

Comment: This can be done programmatically ?  Or would I have to setup that ramdisk using an installer or manually?

Comment: You can set it up in your OS, there are RAM-disks for all major OS's.

Comment: On 32 bits Windows the ram limit is 3 gb for the entire system. A ram disk is not an option.

Comment: Try looking at https://www.megaleecher.net/RAMDisk for using more than 4GB on 32-bit Windows as a ramdisk.